# VSCode typescript build takes forever after installing nvm-windows

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I had installed nvm-windows as recommended here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-windows

Unfortunately seems now compilation is broken : Ctrl+Shift+B has disappeared from Terminal though it seems to launch task but it takes forever.

Should I reinstalle vscode or what ?

Comment: Have you tried using [volta](http://volta.sh/) instead of nvm?

Comment: @equiman thanks never heard about it.

Comment: @equiman do you know if I need to uninstall nvm before volta ?

Comment: yes, can't have both and neither node installed (from binary)